# Is it necessary to call removeAllObjects on NSArray when deallocating under ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I'm debugging an application which uses ARC in Instrument at the moment. It seems that if `Object A` contains an array which contains `Object B`s, I need to explicitly call `removeAllObjects` method on the instance variable `contents`, which is an `NSArray`.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"%@ deallocing", self);
   [_contents removeAllObjects];
}
```

If I were to comment out the line `[_contents removeAllObjects]`, Instruments show that objects which are contained in the array are still alive after the parent object is deallocated. I thought when `NSArray` deallocates it automatically reduces the retain count for elements contained in it. Why is explicit removal necessary then? Is this behavior a side effect of debugging itself?

Comment: Hm. It seems more likely, that the array is still around,even after the instance of `A` has been `dealloc`ed. Are you sure, that the reference held by the instance of `A` is the only reference to the array there is in your app. at that time?

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. For whatever reason I need to switch focus in of the app to the foreground before the objects would deallocate (The NSLog messages would print). Previously the focus was always on XCode and the console. Looks like explicitly removing contents from array changed the timing of deallocation.

Answer (score 3):

Normally:

- if an object is dealloced all its ivars are dealloced.
- if an array is dealloced, all the objects in an array have their retain counts decremented.

If I had to guess, you are using the object in the array in a block somewhere.  With ARC, blocks are the primary source of memory leaks.

Where or how are you using the array and the objects in the array?